# Where do the Dharma stations get power?

Tags: lost

In *LOST*, we see a few Dharma stations in various states of repair. Specifically, we see The Swan and The Pearl stations running with only the barest of crews, or no crew at all. Both have electricity, and at least the Swan has running water. We see that there is a breaker box that controls the electricity in the Swan. When the supply drop is made, food is provided, but no fuel for any generator.

### What is providing power to the Dharma stations?

Comment: Juliet tells Jack that [the Tempest](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/The_Tempest) is a power station, but everything about the station seems related to the chemical weapons. Even LostPedia doesn't mention it being a power station.

Comment: Dharmad if I know mate

Answer (score 4):

According to Sayid, The Swan was powered by a geothermal generator in one of the season 2 episodes. As far as the rest of the island goes, there's speculation that The Tempest provided power via underground conduits. See the following link for more info:

https://www.reddit.com/r/lost/comments/33ww8w/where_do_the_others_get_power/cqp4n86